# Is oculus quest2 available for autoware

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am handling Oculus Quest2 to visualize the camera or Rviz scene to the device.

I found some oculus supporting UIs in the runtime manager and found relevant documents.
https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/tree/2f18aae2976e350eb4c3b2c320a9ff07b8bca3d9/ui/oculus/ofw

Has anyone tried something similar like this approach?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380393/is-oculus-quest2-available-for-autoware/) by [Kim_3957](https://answers.ros.org/users/76143/kim_3957/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sorry but the Oculus Quest is not officially supported by Autoware.ai.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kim_3957](https://answers.ros.org/users/76143/kim_3957/) on 2021-06-17**:
Thank you for your reply..